# can a regex match cn.cn. or ti.ti. but not vv.pp. or aa.bb.?

Tags: regex

is it possible with regex to match a particular sequence repeating it self rather than number of letters? I would like to be able to match cn.cn. or ti.ti. or xft.xft. but not vv.pp. or aa.bb. and I do not seam to be able to do that with (\w\w.)+ opposed to \w+.\w+. in the first case I want in fact to use only one occurrence, like cn. or ti. in the second I want to keep v.p. or a.b.
thanks for any help.

Comment: sure! `(\w)\1\.(\w)\2`

Comment: I feel like this isn't very clear. You say you want to match cn.cn and not aa.bb, and then later on you say you want to 'keep v.p or a.b' and I don't know what it is you want to match. If you want to match 'aa.bb' then what Adam said is correct. If you want to match 'cn.cn' you will want (\w{1})\.\1

Comment: Thanks a lot! with Adam's solution I can make that distinction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your flavor of regex, you can use backreferences in your regex to match an earlier group. Your question title and question body disagree, however, on what exactly is supposed to be matched. I'll answer in Python as that's the flavor I'm most familiar with.

```
# match vv.pp., no match cn.cn.
re.match(r"(\w)\1\.(\w)\2\.", some_text)

# match cn.cn., no match vv.pp.
re.match(r"(\w{2})\.\1\.", some_text)
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited the title to match the content of the body. What I was interested in was distinguishing the two and your answer allowed me to do so.